# how to add numbers to clock from 1 to 12, i just create circle

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Color;

import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class Clock extends GraphicsProgram {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void run() {
        GOval tofig = createFilledCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, 200, Color.black);
        add(tofig);
        GOval lala = createFilledCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, 180, Color.white);
        add(lala);
    }


    private GOval createFilledCircle(double x, double y, double r, Color color) {
        GOval circle = new GOval(x - r, y - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);
        circle.setFilled(true);
        circle.setColor(color);
        return circle;
    }

    // Ignore this;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Clock().start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190729/discussion-on-question-by-anna-how-to-add-numbers-to-clock-from-1-to-12-i-just).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for the trigonometry part of what you're trying to do that you and I have kinda worked on together:

```
public class DrawCircle {

    static final double twopi = Math.PI * 2;
    static final double fudge = 0.000001;

    private static void drawHourLabels(double center_x, double center_y, double radius) {

        int steps = 12;
        for (double angle = 0.0; angle < (twopi - fudge); angle += twopi/steps) {
            double x_offset = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
            double y_offset = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
            double x = center_x + x_offset;
            double y = center_y + y_offset;

            // Here you'd do the actual drawing of each hour label at the coordinates x,y.  We'll just print them for now.
            System.out.println(String.format("%f %f", x, y));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
//        drawHourLabels(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, 220); // <-- you'd do something like this in your "run" method.

        // Draw clock labels around circle with center at 400x200 of radius 220
        drawHourLabels(400, 600, 220);
    }
}
```

The 'fudge' value is used because floating point arithmetic isn't perfectly precise.  By the time we've added 12 floating point values together to get to 2 * Math.PI, we might be a little over or under.  We want to make sure we don't process the 12:00 position again at the end of the loop because we computed a value just a little smaller than 2 * Math.PI.  So we add a "fudge factor" that's really small, but guaranteed to be bigger than any floating point inaccuracy we've accumulated.

Comment: Thank you, can you say next step? @Steve

Comment: yes.  it's as I say in the comment in the code.  You now have each of the 12 sets of screen coordinates for your text.  So now you have to figure out how to actually draw the numbers at each of those coordinates.  I don't know anything about the package you're using for drawing, so I don't even know off hand what that code will look like.

Comment: String a = Integer.toString(i);

Comment: If you have 'i' as an integer, then yes, although if you're starting at 0 then you want to use 'i + 1'.

Comment: String a = Double.toString(i); like this? @Steve

Comment: Can you look at my full code? and you'd make some corrections

Comment: Sure.  Where is your code so I can look at it?   Oh...I see.  They don't like you doing that, putting non-answers in as an answer.  You should delete your Answer. 
 Better to put it in your question.  You can leave the old stuff there and just add a new code block

Comment: ok I understand but did you analyze my code?Because  this code do not give me result that I want

Comment: can you say next step?

Comment: You have to delete your answer and put the code in your question before i can answer much more.  I don't want what we're doing to get us in trouble.  Please move your new code to your question.  `String a = Double.toString(angle)` won't work because `angle` isn't `1, 2, 3, 4...`.  What I would do is create an `hour` variable that starts at 0 before the loop, and gets incremented by 1 each time through the loop.  So then `hour` will be `1, 2, 3, 4...` and then you can do `Integer.toString(hour)` to get the string you want to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this simple example from me.

```
/**
 * Draw text elements from 1 to 12 inside a circle
 * @return a group of text elements from 1 to 12
 */
public strictfp static Group drawText() {
    //a list for storing text numbers
    List<Text> numbersInClock = new ArrayList<>();
    //create a group of shapes
    Group group = new Group();
    //set it to x,y positions
    group.setLayoutX(150);
    group.setLayoutY(150);
    //numbers corresponding to angle calculations
    int[] numbers = {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2};
    double[] angles = {0, 0.166666666667, 0.333333333334,0.5, 0.666666666667, 0.833333333334, 1, 1.166666666667, 1.33333333334, 1.5, 1.666666666667, 1.83333333334};
    int i = 0;
    for (double angle : angles) {    
        //Calculated formula for x,y positions of each number within a circle
        //(x,y) = (rcos(angle),rsin(angle))  
        int r = 90; // length of radius, a bit shorter to put it inside a circle
        //calculate x and y positions based on formula for numbers within a circle
        double x = r * Math.cos(angle*Math.PI);
        double y = r * Math.sin(angle*Math.PI);
        //create a text element consiting a coressponding number
        Text text = new Text(x, y, String.valueOf(numbers[i++]));
        //add it to a list
        numbersInClock.add(text);
    }
    //add all text elements to a group
    group.getChildren().addAll(numbersInClock);
    //return a group
    return group;

}
```

Full code can be acquired from here: [https://github.com/MomirSarac/JavaFX-Circle-Clock-Image](http://source%20code%20on%20github.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use sin and cos to know where to set your text.
Sine and Cosine are two math operators that take in an angle in radians and give out number beetween -1 and 1 to know how to multiply to get coordinates

[you can learn more here](http://setosa.io/ev/sine-and-cosine/)

Comment: This is very helpful.  Nice link.  I just submitted some suggested edits to your text though, to be technically correct:  "You can use sin and cos to know where to set your text. Sine and Cosine are two math operators that take in an angle in radians and give out a number between -1 and 1 to know how to multiply to get coordinates"