# How to draw a line at the end of an arc?

Tags: java, android, canvas

How do I draw a line at the end of an arc like so?

[image: example image]

Here is the code I'm currently using to draw the arc

```
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        canvasWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        canvasHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        padding = strokeWidth * 0.9f;
        arcAngle = 360 * 0.8f;
        rectF.set(padding, padding, canvasWidth - padding, canvasHeight - padding);
        arcRadius = (canvasWidth - padding) / 2f;
        arcBottomHeight = arcRadius * (float) (1 - Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI));
    }
```

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float startAngle = 270 - arcAngle / 2f;
        float finishedSweepAngle = progress / (float) getMax() * arcAngle;
        float finishedStartAngle = startAngle;

        canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, arcAngle, false, unfinishedPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, finishedStartAngle, finishedSweepAngle, false, finishedPaint);
}
```

This draws 2 arcs on top of each other, with the colored arc (finishedPaint) representing the progress.

I want to use canvas.drawLine() to draw the line at the end of the arc, but am unsure how to get the coordinates to specify the start and stop coordinates of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Use trig.  You know the radius of the arc and the angle it ends at.  The x is `radius*sin(endangle)+xcenter`, the y is `radius*cos(endangle)+ycenter`.  Then draw the line at that same angle where that lies.

Comment: I like your idea. Something similar is implemented here in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363902/how-to-add-numbers-to-clock-from-1-to-12-i-just-create-circle/55365869#55365869 so @khorik take a look for x and y.